# if $x \in \mathbb R$ and $x^2 - 4x +4 < 0$ , then $|x| = 1$ .

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I have to prove that if $x \in \mathbb R$  and $x^2 - 4x +4 < 0$ , then $|x|  = 1$ .

**My Attempt :** I proved  it by contraposition.

If $|x| \neq 1$ , $x^2 - 4x +4 \geq 0$  .

We know for any $x \in \mathbb R$ , $x^2 - 4x +4 \geq 0$  .

So if $|x| \neq 1$ , $x^2 - 4x +4 \geq 0$  .

Have I gone wrong anywhere ? Can anyone please check it ?

Comment: $x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2$ is always non-negative

Comment: Note that $x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2$. Hence $(x-2)^2<0$ never happens!

Comment: Also, your prove by contraposition is fine!

Comment: What can make sense is :$x^2-4x+4 \le 0 \implies (x-2)^2 \le 0 \implies x-2=0 \implies x=2.$

Comment: Please check my proof. I know the statement is quite awkward. But I have to prove it.@ZAhmed

Comment: Your proof seems good.

Comment: Both the statement and your proof are fine. The implication $P\Rightarrow Q$ here happens to be true simply because $P$ is not true (and you know the truth table of an implication, if you assume nonsense, you can conclude whatever you want). 

A proof by contraposition is always going to work for $P\Rightarrow Q$ if $P$ is false. Indeed, you don't even need to assume $\neg Q$ to prove $\neg P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof by contrapositive is completely fine.

Indeed, you can prove in the same way that

> if $x^2-4x+4<0$, then $x$ is integer/irrational/equal to $\pi$/…

where “…” stands for any property expressible in the language of real numbers. Even

> if $x^2-4x+4<0$, then $|x|\ne1$

follows in the same way.

The reason is that any statement of the form “if $P$ then $Q$”, where $P$ is false, is true.

Remember that “if $P$ then $Q$” is logically equivalent to “not $P$ or $Q$” (at least in classical logic, which I assume you’re dealing with), so you see that falsehood of $P$ entails truth of “if $P$ then $Q$”.